# Multiple coefplots: loop quotes issue

Tags: loops, stata, quotes, coefplot

I'm trying to create a loop in STata that creates coefplots, which show the coefficients for multiple regressions for subgroups of a population. Each of the plots would use different regressors.

I'm running into an issue with quotations using the loop. Ideally each of the graphs would look like the picture I included.
[image]

```
sysuse auto, clear 
replace foreign = 3 if (rep78 == 3) 
regress price mpg length if foreign == 1
estimates store mpg_foreign_1_length
regress price mpg length if foreign == 0
estimates store mpg_foreign_0_length
regress price mpg length if foreign == 3
estimates store mpg_foreign_3_length

regress price mpg trunk if foreign == 1
estimates store mpg_foreign_1_trunk 
regress price mpg trunk if foreign == 0
estimates store mpg_foreign_0_trunk 
regress price mpg trunk if foreign == 3
estimates store mpg_foreign_3_trunk 


global list_graphing "trunk" "length"

foreach x of global list_graphing {
        coefplot "mpg_foreign_3_`x' mpg_foreign_1_`x'" ||, drop(_cons) 
   }
   

  foreach x of global list_graphing {
        coefplot "mpg_foreign_3_`x' mpg_foreign_1_`x' mpg_foreign_0_`x'" ||, drop(_cons)
   }
   
 //invalid something: quotes do not match


   foreach x of global list_graphing {
        coefplot "mpg_foreign_3_`x'" "mpg_foreign_1_`x'" "mpg_foreign_0_`x'" 
   }
```

The first graph displays essentially what I'm trying to create; however, it doesn't work when a third variable is added. I can't split them up with quotes because, as the code clearly shows, that makes it so the coefficients are no longer on the same graph.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much experience with `coefplot`, but it seems this works if you just don't use quotes (indeed, I'm somewhat surprised that it does work with quotes sometimes).

```
sysuse auto

replace foreign = 3 if (rep78 == 3) 
regress price mpg length if foreign == 1
estimates store mpg_foreign_1_length
regress price mpg length if foreign == 0
estimates store mpg_foreign_0_length
regress price mpg length if foreign == 3
estimates store mpg_foreign_3_length

regress price mpg trunk if foreign == 1
estimates store mpg_foreign_1_trunk 
regress price mpg trunk if foreign == 0
estimates store mpg_foreign_0_trunk 
regress price mpg trunk if foreign == 3
estimates store mpg_foreign_3_trunk 


global list_graphing trunk length

foreach x of global list_graphing {
        coefplot mpg_foreign_3_`x' mpg_foreign_1_`x' ||, drop(_cons) 
   }
   

  foreach x of global list_graphing {
        coefplot mpg_foreign_3_`x' mpg_foreign_1_`x' mpg_foreign_0_`x' ||, drop(_cons)
   }
   

   foreach x of global list_graphing {
        coefplot mpg_foreign_3_`x' mpg_foreign_1_`x' mpg_foreign_0_`x' 
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in your definition

```
global list_graphing "trunk" "length"
```

Stata strips the outermost quotation marks as delimiters and your macro is left holding

```
trunk" "length
```

which then causes problems downstream. If you needed to have the matched quotation marks inside the global macro, then your definition should be

```
global list_graphing `" "trunk" "length" "'
```

but as already answered you don't need any quotation marks here.